# New column with total number of elements in a column comprised of lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to see if there's an easy way to create a column showing the total number of elements from a list in another column (i.e. ment) in the screenshot.

So in the `df['ment']` I have 2 users each in rows 1 and 2. I would like to generate and attach a column to my dataframe that shows these totals. Is there an easy regex function that can accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to add tags `pandas`, `dataframe`. As for the question, perhaps in this case a number of users = a number of '@'. Regex could be something like this: `number_of_users = len(re.findall("@", df['ment'])`.

Comment: I tried the following but I'm getting an error message. 

df['hashcount']=df['hashtag'].value_counts()

Comment: Mere proof that your question is really more about `pandas` and `dataframe` than `python`.